# Projection semigroup of an isolated eigenvalue

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, banach-spaces, operator-theory, semigroups-of-operators

I'm currently working with a paper and I don't get something there. Let $A$ be a closed operator on a Banach space $X$ and $\lambda \in \sigma(A)$ an isolated eigenvalue, i.e. there is a $r > 0$ with $\sigma(A) \cap B_r(\lambda) = \{\lambda\}$. Now one can define the spectral projection
$$ \Pi_\lambda := \frac{1}{2\pi \mathrm i} \int_{\gamma_s} R(z,A)\,dz \in \mathcal L(X),$$
where $\gamma_s: [0,1] \to \mathbb C, \gamma_s(t) = s e^{2\pi \mathrm i t}$. By virtue of Cauchy's theorem this definition is invariant of $0 < s < r$. This is all clear to me. Now there is a "semigroup" defined in the followong manner:
$$ S_\lambda(t) := \frac{1}{2\pi \mathrm i} \int_{\gamma_s} e^{tz}R(z,A)\,dz.$$
Again it is clear to me that this is well-defined, $S_\lambda(t) \in \mathcal L(X)$ for all $t \geq 0$ and that $S_\lambda(t + s) = S_\lambda(t) S_\lambda(s)$ holds for all $t, s \geq 0$, due to resolvent identity, Fubini's and Cauchy's theorem. Since $e^{tz} \to 1$ for $t \to 0$ locally uniformly I even know that $\Vert S_\lambda(t) - S_\lambda(0) \Vert \to 0$ for $t \to 0$. The only thing I miss out on is that I can't get why $S_\lambda(0) = I$ might hold, since one has clearly that $S(0) = \Pi_\lambda$. This is the only thing that's missing for $(S_\lambda(t))_{t \geq 0}$ to be a $C_0$-semigroup (actually it is even norm-continuous). So why should $(S_\lambda(t))_{t \geq 0}$ be a semigroup?

Comment: Everything you wrote is correct. There are at least two reasons why one could call $\mathcal{S} := (S_\lambda(t))_{t \ge 0}$ a *semigroup*: (i) The notion semigroup is used differently by different authors in the literature. Sometimes an operator family $(T(t))_{t \ge 0}$ is called a semigroup if merely $T(s+t) = T(s)T(t)$ for all $s,t \ge 0$; (ii) since the operator family $\mathcal{S}$ acts trivially on $\ker \Pi_0$, one is usually only interested in its action on the range of $\Pi_0$, and the restriction of $\mathcal{S}$ to this range is indeed a $C_0$-semigroup.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense to me. Thanks for the insight.